# How can I make an object emit a single particle with predefined frequency

Tags: particles, physics

I have no actual blend file for this, as I have not managed to make it work, but in essence I would like something along the lines of a tap that drips water every 1/2 sec or so. Is this at all possible? Any tutorials I have found simply emit a no. Of particles at random with no set frequency.

Answer (score 5):

If the frame rate of the output is 25, and the particle system duration is 200, we need 16 particles to have one every half second.

[image]

You can for instance use a mesh with a single vertex (if you want the drip to be at an exact position):

[image]

Comment: @Xarwolf192 The answer from lemon is exactly how I do it. But even a dripping tap does not necessarily have a perfect frequency, the main thing you need to make sure is that you set the number of particles low enough for the span of the animation so that there is no chance to get more than a single particle at once. Only thing I would change is setting the normal velocity to 0 m/s so the drops won't jump up at first. But that's just nit-picking from me  ;-)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, if from vertices the particle won't jump as no normal (i made the gif before changing the setting above). And you're right water drip is pseudo random.

Comment: Oh of course, you're right... no normal direction to follow ;) My bad..

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, interesting about that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovJcsL7vyrk

Comment: Yes, very interesting video. I've been reading a lot about chaos theory etc. in the past. But actually the particles for this water dripping won't have to be erratic since the water flow shouldn't change much ;)